# Getting Wrong Target exception on EJB local call

Tags: java, ejb, jboss-seam

```
[TxPolicy] javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Wrong target. class com.sample.mock.service.MockFinanceService for public long com.sample.mock.service.MockFinanceService.createFinancialTransaction(com.sample.mock.service.params.MockFinanceTrasactionParam)
```

My Stateless bean class is:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "MockFinanceService")
public class MockFinanceService implements MockFinanceServiceLocal {
....
}
```

Local interface is:

```
@Local
public interface MockFinanceServiceLocal {
    public long createFinancialTransaction(MockFinanceTrasactionParam mockFinanceTrasactionParam);
}
```

I'm calling the service as follows:

```
MockFinanceServiceLocal mockFinanceServiceLocal = (MockFinanceServiceLocal) new InitialContext().lookup("FinanceEAR/MockFinanceService/local");
......
mockFinanceServiceLocal.createFinancialTransaction(mockFinanceTrasactionParam);
```

Please help me to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is my application have a Ear scoped class loader settings. Otherwise local reference should work even from different ear deployed on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in some JBoss versions that produce this error when using the `@Local` interface and the server is configured to pass values by reference. If this is the case, then simply using `@Remote` instead of `@Local` should work. See: https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/28349

Is there a reason why you're doing the lookup manually? Can't you inject the EJB?

```
@EJB
private MockFinanceServiceLocal mockFinanceServiceLocal;

public void myAction() {
    // ...
    mockFinanceServiceLocal.createFinancialTransaction(mockFinanceTransactionParams);
}
```

Also, you tagged the question as `jboss-seam` related. There's nothing in your question, or the problem it relates to, that is Seam-related...

Answer (score 0):

You error suggests that you have problem on this line

```
mockFinanceServiceLocal.createFinancialTransaction(mockFinanceTrasactionParam);
```

**What is `mockFinanceTrasactionParam` ?**  **Where is it defined ?**

Comment: mockFinanceTrasactionParam is defined in the client jar of EJB project where MockFinanceService resides.

Comment: please post that config file too.

Comment: I have only annotated configuration.